# How to setup all ForeignKey & OneToOneField fields into raw_id_fields

Tags: python, django, django-admin

For example I have this 3 fields as `set_soal`, `soal` and `folder`. I need to assign all of this fields into `raw_id_fields` inside the `admin.ModelAdmin` without add manually per-single fields.

```
class DaftarSoal(TimeStampedModel):
    ....
    set_soal = ForeignKey(SetSoal, ...)
    soal = ForeignKey(Soal, ...)
    folder = ForeignKey(Folder, ...)
```

the basic way to enable raw id fields inside the `admin.ModelAdmin` look like this;

```
@admin.register(DaftarSoal, site=admin_site)
class DaftarSoalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ('set_soal', 'soal', 'folder')    # manually
```

[image: screenshot 1]

But, can I setup all that `OneToOneField` and `ForeignKey` fields automatically into `raw_id_fields` without add it manually? such as applying the class mixin, for example:

```
class CustomAdminMixin:
    raw_id_fields = ()

    def __init__(self):
        self.setup_raw_id_fields()

    def setup_raw_id_fields(self):
        # search all OneToOneField and ForeignKey fields.
        # and assign into variable `raw_id_fields` above.
```

and to implement it;

```
@admin.register(DaftarSoal, site=admin_site)
class DaftarSoalAdmin(CustomAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass



@admin.register(AnotherModel, site=admin_site)
class AnotherModelAdmin(CustomAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inspect the model, and search through the fields for instances of `ForeignKey`, and add the name to the tuple, for example with:

```
from django.db.models import (ForeignKey, OneToOneField)

class CustomAdminMixin:
    raw_id_fields = ()

    def __init__(self, model, admin_site, *args, **kwargs):
        self.raw_id_fields = self.setup_raw_id_fields(model)
        super().__init__(model, admin_site, *args, **kwargs)

    def setup_raw_id_fields(self, model):
        return tuple(
            f.name
            for f in model._meta.get_fields()
            if isinstance(f, ForeignKey) or isinstance(f, OneToOneField)
        )
```

A `OneToOneField` is a subclass of a `ForeignKey`, so there is no need to make search for a `OneToOneField`.